# additionalProperties support multiple defined types

Tags: openapi, openapi-generator-maven-plugin

I want to create schemas, in which additionalProperties will be the type of string or boolean, or number. It can not be a complex object.

How can I achieve that I was using

```
components:
  schemas:
    SomeSchema:
      type: object
      additionalProperties:
        anyOf:
         - type: string
         - type: number
         - type: integer
         - type: boolean
```

But when generating code using open codegen version 6.6.0. It is creating an empty class SomeSchema.

```
  schemas:
    SomeSchema:
      type: object
      additionalProperties:
        type:
         - string
         - number
         - integer
         - boolean
```

Tried this. It is creating HashMap<String, Object>. which is logically correct but the above schemas are not valid as per open API specification 3.0.X

https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/data-types/

Comment: Looks like a bug or limitation. Open an issue in the OpenAPI Generator repository: https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/issues